Dynamic image as a Background/Watermark in RTF Template
I am trying to add a background to the PDFs created using a BI Publisher RTF template. The image details are part of the XML.
I tried both Background and Watermark but in either case, since there is no alt text available it is not working.
I tried to add an image and move it to the background but when I generate the PDF, the image moves down.
I also tried to import a different rtf template with a background and call a template to see if that would work, but no luck.

@k-j your HelloWord.pdf is exactly what I am trying to achieve. I must have done something wrong because this approach didn't work for me earlier. Look at output pdf: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/B4A8K25x#link
